# Postgres SQL SELECT and UPDATE behaving differently

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I can't see why the SELECT below finds 7065 records, but the update says it updates 13935 records, which is every record in the table.

Can anyone suggest why?

```
superfrr=# select count(*)  from fromemailaddress LEFT JOIN email ON 
(email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress) 
WHERE LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';
 count
-------
  7065
```

But:

```
superfrr=# update fromemailaddress set call=true  from fromemailaddress 
 as fea LEFT JOIN email ON (email.fromemailaddress = fea.fromemailaddress)
 WHERE LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';
UPDATE 13935
```

Comment: Perhaps `count` does not include null values?

Comment: @EMett `COUNT(*)` includes everything, `NULL` values included and also if a row contains `NULL` values entirely ( [example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1de6e/1) )

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Try `update FEA` instead of  `update fromemailaddress` - how many rows  are being updated ? :)

Comment: Why are you using a LEFT JOIN if you want to apply a condition to the second table? Wouldn't it be more straightforward to directly use INNER JOIN? Besides that, I never used a JOIN in an UPDATE sentence (but I'm more used to Oracle, and dealing with these cases with EXISTS / IN clauses)

Comment: Follow-up with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31964681/939860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `~` suggests that you are using Postgres.  If so, the two queries are doing very different things.  In Postgres, you don't include the table being updated in the `from` clause.

So, I think you want:

```
update fromemailaddress
    set call = true 
    from email
    where email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress and
          LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';
```

Your version is updating all rows in `fromemailaddress` because there is no condition connecting `fromemailaddress` in the `update` clause and `fea` in the `from` clause.

Also note:  the `left join` is unnecessary because the `where` clause turns it into an inner join anyway.

Comment: Also worth noting the functionality of that operator being a case sensitive regex match.

Answer (score 1):

You must count on primary key it will returns all values because count do not work on null values. Hopes this helps thanks

```
select count(PrimaryKey Field)  from fromemailaddress LEFT JOIN email ON
```

(email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress) 
WHERE LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';