# How does the FROM side of an UPDATE relate to the table targeted for UPDATE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

The following query (sourced from here [Postgres SQL SELECT and UPDATE behaving differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964172/postgres-sql-select-and-update-behaving-differently))

```
update fromemailaddress
    set call = true 
    from email
    where email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress and
          LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';
```

The way I read it is:

```
Line 1: update fromemailaddress
```

-- we tell the database that we are updating the fromemailaddress table

```
Line 2:        set call = true
```

-- we tell the database that the field named "call" will be set to true

```
Line 3:        from email
Line 4:         where email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress and
Line 5:              LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';
```

-- OK now things are getting fuzzy.  What actually happens here? It appears that somehow the database takes the result of the query in lines 3 4 and 5, but how does that tell it which rows to update in the fromemailaddress table? What is the pseudocode? Is it something like:

```
for each row in (query from lines 3, 4, 5)
    set call=true?
```

I just can't see how the FROM side of the SQL update relates to the other side.

UPDATE:

Following the valuable links in @Erwin's answer below lead me to this information that gets to the core of what I was trying to understand:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the
>   target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and
>   each output row of the join represents an update operation for the
>   target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces
>   at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a
>   target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other
>   table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to
>   update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily
>   predictable.
>
> Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within
>   sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than
>   using a join.

Comment: The `where` clause connects the two tables.

Comment: So are the number of rows in the connected tables are always less than or equal to the number of rows in the update target table? What if the email table has more rows that match the where clause, than the number of rows in the update target? I can't make sense of what would happen if the FROM side of the statement had more rows than the UPDATE target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UPDATE` query you display is exactly the same as:

```sql
UPDATE fromemailaddress f
SET    call = true 
FROM  (
   SELECT fromemailaddress
   FROM   email 
   WHERE  subject ILIKE '%tester%'
   ) e
WHERE  e.fromemailaddress = f.fromemailaddress;
```

`subject ILIKE '%tester%'` is a faster equivalent for `subject ~ 'tester'`. Details for `LIKE`, `ILIKE` and regular expression matching (`~`) [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) or in this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

And ***effectively*** the same as:

```sql
UPDATE fromemailaddress f
SET    call = true
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM email e
   WHERE  e.fromemailaddress = f.fromemailaddress
   AND    e.subject ILIKE '%tester%'
   );
```

Use this instead.

If there should be multiple rows in table `email` with the same `fromemailaddress` matching a row in `fromemailaddress`, then this form only executes ***one*** update per row, unlike your unfortunate original.

Don't be confused by the fact that `fromemailaddress` is used as column and as table name here.

Read the manual carefully [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-update.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html). In particular this bit:

> ***from_list***
>
> A list of table expressions, allowing columns from other tables to
> appear in the `WHERE` condition and the update expressions. This is
> similar to the list of tables that can be specified in the [`FROM` Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)
> of a `SELECT` statement. Note that the target table must not appear in
> the ***from_list***, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must
> appear with an alias in the ***from_list***).

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that the UPDATE target table must mentioned in the FROM side of the SQL statement, in order to link the UPDATE side of the statement to the FROM side of the statement?

Comment: @DukeDougal: Au contraire. I added a quote from the manual (which you should read).

Comment: Thanks @erwin.  Also a point to you for using "Au contraire", a term all too rarely used these days.  That's some good manual references, putting me on the right track thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's an inner join.  Records are only updated where `email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress`.  If it's a not a one-to-one relationship, then either the one record from `email` will update multiple records in `fromemailaddress`, or the many records in `email` will update the single record in `fromemailaddress`.

The former is just fine.  The latter is non-deterministic, I believe, if you're writing a value from the source table.  There's no guaranteed result because the query doesn't define an order.  It will be done in whatever order the query engine chooses. For example:

```
update fromemailaddress
set call = email.call
from email
where email.fromemailaddress = fromemailaddress.fromemailaddress and
      LOWER(email.subject) ~ 'tester';
```

Now you might have a problem if the email/fromemailaddress relationship is many-to-one.

Since this particular query is always setting the value to a static value, there's no determinism problem.